# bookmarklet to apply xslt stylesheet to a displayed xml file

Tags: bookmarklet, xslt

How would I write a bookmarklet that applies a given XSLT stylesheet to XML file that is displayed in, e.g., firefox? The XML Document is already loaded in the browser and displayed without a stylesheet, and the XSLT is available under a fixed URL which should be encoded in the bookmarklet.

Comment: Is the XML document itself rendered in the browser window? Or is it already transformed by an XSLT stylesheet? How/where is the stylesheet "given"? The Mozilla XSLT API is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_the_mozilla_javascript_interface_to_xsl_transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

A bookmarklet for applying an XSLT stylesheet to an XML document - just insert the base64 encoded xsl in atob("") - tested on firefox

```
javascript: (function() {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var ss = parser.parseFromString(atob(""), 'application/xml');
  var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(ss);
  var newdoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(content.document);
  var myWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(newdoc.documentElement.innerHTML), "_blank", "");
  myWindow.focus();
}());
```

ref: https://gist.github.com/gosub/c7576b0c99ffdd7e993c

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script to apply xslt on xml in the bookmark within parenthesis of 'javascript()'.

Here is the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=cdcatalog

Firstly, host the xslt and xml so as to avoid any access issues of files from javascript.

There are some modifications which are needed in the script:

1. In the reference above, update the following:

   ```
       xml=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
       xsl=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
   ```

   to

   ```
       xml=loadXMLDoc(window.location.href.toString());
       xsl=loadXMLDoc("http://<path>/<filename>.xsl");
   ```
2. Save the output in a file as per the output set in your `xslt(xml/html/text)` or simply display it in alert for copying and using.

Thanks